# Running foreach loop powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, doc

I'm having a difficult time getting this to work. This script will ask for the location for the GAM.exe, and then the location of a CSV. Then it should run a foreach loop executing GAM with the said variables to add bulk users to google docs. An example of working code:

```
$Gamfile 'create user' crashtestdummy 'firstname' "Crash" 'lastname' "Test Dummy" 'password' "BuckleUp"
```

The above works, and will add the user Crashtestdummy@School.org

The issue I am having is in the foreach loop. I just get:

> Unexpected token '$User'
>    Unexpected token ' 'password' '

### Thanks in advance!

```
Function Get-GamFile($initialDirectory)
{   
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") |
  Out-Null

  $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
  $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
  $OpenFileDialog.filter = "GAM File (gam.exe)| gam.exe"
  $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
  $OpenFileDialog.filename
} #end function Get-GamFile

$GamFile = Get-GamFile


Function Get-CSV($initialDirectory)
{   
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") |
  Out-Null

  $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
  $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
  $OpenFileDialog.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
  $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
  $OpenFileDialog.filename
} #end function Get-CSV

$GetCSV = Get-CSV
$CSV = Import-Csv $GetCSV

Write-Host $GamFile
Write-Host $GetCSV

Function AddUsers {    
  foreach ($User in $CSV) {
    Write-Host Making User $User.firstname $user.lastname
    $GamFile 'create user' $User.firstname 'firstname' $User.firstname 'lastname' $User.lastname 'password' $User.Password    
  }
}

AddUsers


#$Gamfile 'create user' crashtestdummy 'firstname' "Crash" 'lastname' "Test Dummy" 'password' "BuckleUp"
```

Comment: If you just wrote this to screen `"'$GamFile' create user '$($User.firstname)' firstname '$($User.firstname)' lastname '$($User.lastname)' password '$($User.Password)'"` does that look ok? If it does should just be able to put an `&` infront of it to make it execute. Any of your last names have spaces maybe? Just spit balling.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Well, I had forgot to put a & in the loop
and now it's no longer producing errors!!! but it's still acting like I just ran GAM.exe
And not:
 GAM.exe 'create user' BobTest 'first name' bob "last name" test 'Password' temppass

Comment: perhaps `'create user'` is being interpeted as one element when it really is two. Remove the quotes. `& $GamFile create user $User.firstname ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just forgot the `&` required to execute an expression as an exe. Try this:

```
& $GamFile 'create user' $User.firstname 'firstname' $User.firstname 'lastname' $User.lastname 'password' $User.Password
```

As @Matt suggested, maybe the quotes are overzealous?

```
& $GamFile create user $User.firstname 'firstname' $User.firstname 'lastname' $User.lastname 'password' $User.Password
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Well, I had forgot to put a & in the loop
and now it's no longer producing errors!!! but it's still acting like I just ran GAM.exe
And not:
 GAM.exe 'create user' BobTest 'first name' bob "last name" test 'Password' temppass

Comment: I do:
Write-host $GamFile 'create user' $User.firstname 'firstname' $User.firstname 'lastname' $User.lastname 'password' $User.Password

The copy what is spit out past it into a shell it creates the users. So it seems like my filtering is corrected. It got to be something simple that I'm over looking that powershell doesn't like.